# How do I debug this Identity Server error: unauthorized client Invalid redirect_uri in this Blazor application

Tags: blazor, identityserver4

Let me provide a bit more context, I am working on a task to make a copy of a working Blazor application where I made a copy of the folders under c:/inetpub/wwwroot/. One folder, we will call the /BQM => created a new copy of this folder called /BQM.DEV. I repeated this same process with the folder /BQM.API => created a new copy called /BQM.DEV.API. BQM is the Application, and BQM.API is the web.api.

When I type "https://localhost:43370", the application works fine, the Login screen appears, but this is pointing to a QA database and we want to have a new instance which points to a DEV database.

Thus, in IIS, I created a new website for the BQM.DEV.API and pointed the path to c:/inetpub/wwwroot/BQM.DEV.API and I set the port to 44383 the BQM.API is set to port 44382. I also created a new website for BQM.DEV and pointed the path to c:/inetpub/wwwroot/BQM.DEV and set the port to 44371

Next I updated the following config files:

appsetting.json: working version:

```
{
   "AzureAD": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Domain": "mydomain.com",
      "TenantId": "3520c07b-xxxx-4503-b2b9-509a97b58c8f",
      "ClientId": "268428b8-be88-xxxx-9e48-19d20294fe23",
      "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44370/",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
   },
   "Okta": {
      "Issuer": "https://okta.okta.com/oauth2/default",
      "OktaDomain": "https://dev-422955.okta.com/",
      "ClientId": "0oa22wxxxxrNblp86357",
      "ClientSecret": "CwuTAzCi961YPz803xxxxxxSxfLyU4xOjE8KibLx",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
   },
   "BQMApplicationLocation": "https://adcdev028.mycompany.com:44370/",
   "BQMAuthApplicationLocation": "adcdev028.mycompany.com",
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=adcdbs998;Database=BQM_Import;User Id=BQMUser;Password=BQMUser;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Warning"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here is the LaunchSetting.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/BQM.UI",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58015",
      "sslPort": 44371
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BQM.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Made three updates, I changed the port numbers (Redirect, and BQMApplicationLocation) from 44370 to 44371 and I changed the database: from DefaultConnection: BQM_Import to BQM_DEV

typed into the Browser: "https://localhost:43371"

and instead of the Login Screen: I received the following message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One problem I think is that you use the same    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc" for both handlers.

you need to have different urls like

```
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc-azure"
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc-okta"
```

So, that the callback/redirect from the provider goes to the correct handler.

Comment: thank you for your advice, unfortunately, that wasn't the issue. Note: we do have one instance working on another port.